# otool -L: Not a Mach-O filetype

Tags: macos, .net-core, magick.net

I'm trying to use Magick.Net on OS X, and I've been following [this](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/Documentation/CrossPlatform.md) guide to do so. It's a guide for Linux, but OS X is Unix so I *assume* that it should work the same.

I think I'm close to making it work but I've got a problem with the dependencies, and I want to see the dependencies of a `.so` file.
So I Googled how to look a the dependencies of a `.so` file on Linux, and stumbled upon `otool -L`.
This tool looks at the depdencies and also *sees if it can find the dependencies it needs*, which is what I want because it makes everything easier.

But when I run `otool -L Magick.NET-Q8-x64.dll.so`, I get the error message `Not a Mach-O filetype`

So what do I do now? Is there an alternative I can use or am I using the program wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OS X  is Unix so I assume that it should work the same

Here lies the issue. macOS is Unix based, but its executable file format ([Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O)) is unique to macOS / OS X and its predecessor NeXT. `Otool` on macOS expects a Mach-O file, not a linux .so file as they're not binary compatible.

As the guide you linked to states **it is required to have a Linux build machine running**; however,  **L**inux **I**s **N**ot **U**nix.

> Is there an alternative I can use

Follow the instructions in the guide, which states a requirement is a Linux machine and run `otool` under Linux.

Comment: I thought Linux got its name from its creator, Linus Torvalds.